# Limiting the number of selectable files in a Flash file upload dialog

Tags: flash, file, upload, dialog, max

Is this possible through flash?

I have to create a flash uploader where you can define the maximum number of files that can be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. If you allow multiple select in a file upload dialog you cannot control the number of files selected. The best you can do is warn the user ahead of time that only a limited number of files will be used, then prompt the user afterwards if they select too many, perhaps giving them the opportunity select which files they want to upload with a checkbox list.

Comment: Thank you! I will make it this way.

Answer (score 0):

It should be. It's not directly implementing.

Either you use multiple fields and have the user upload one file at a time using FileReference.

Either you use [FileReferenceList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/FileReferenceList.html), but let the user know, you will only upload the first files from the fileList array.